# Python not computing two simple values the right way?

Tags: python, addition

Scratching my head at what seems like the simplest thing ever.

I am working on a polynomial calculator and have been testing it with some values, but python is not adding these two values the way it needs to be.

```
ans_2 = (-0.423604188255 + 0.42368554704)
print("Ans 2 = : " + str(ans_2))
```

I am getting this answer:

```
Ans 2 = : 8.1358785e-05
```

But I should be getting an answer like this:
=0.00009

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You realize 8.1358785e-05 is scientific notation for essentially 0.00009 rounded, right?

Comment: Wow, that is embarrassing my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The value `8.1358785e-05` is scientific notation for the value `.000081358785`. The print function automatically converts to scientific notation for floats under a certain value.

If you want it to print out the value you're looking for, you need to format the string to tell the print function exactly what you're looking for. You can do that like this

```
In [11]: ans_2 = (-0.423604188255 + 0.42368554704)

In [12]: print("Ans 2 = : {:.7f} ".format(ans_2))
Ans 2 = : 0.0000814
```

This will format the string to include seven digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The value 8.1358785e-05 is just another representation of 0.000081358785. 
Whenever you see 'e' in your number means that your value was multiplied by 10 to power of anything that goes after 'e'.

In your case it will be:
8.1358785 * 10 ^ (-5)  = 0.000081358785

For more info look [there](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you are overlooking that there is -ve sign before the first number. That's why you seem to expect the function to return 0.847289735295 (sum of absolute values of operands) instead of the correct answer (their difference according to their sign)